# How to mod rewrite url for php's internal webserver as with apache?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I have checked out an existing php project. It uses apache, but for developing I would like to use php's internal webserver.

The `.htaccess`looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymlinks


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Bonus point but not a must for a solution that would work both ways for apache and php internal webserver, makaing the `.htaccess`obsolete.

As of now, I must request pages via `localhost/index.php/fnord` instead of just `localhost/fnord`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? It's not that you're going to deploy on the php internal server, imho you should develop in an environment which is the closest possible to the production one (well, the other way around). The web server is a critical part of a web application, neglecting it while developing doesn't sound like a bright idea. But maybe I'm underestimating the shipped server

Comment: Don't waste your time develop on a lamp (wamp) stack the php built in server is crap

Comment: @DamienPirsy Ease of setup, a `php -S localhost:1337` is much simpler than setting up a vhost. Quite frankly, I would love to get rid of apache of my dev machine entirely. I would compare it to using `sqlite` for dev or testing purposes and switching to `mysql`for productive systems. Last but not least: I want my setup to be server-agnostic.

Comment: I assume you're developing something not critical, otherwise it would be madness to develop on an environment and then deploy on a totally different one (sqlite and mysql are not the same thing but on a different scale, the same goes for Apache and php internal server).

Comment: How about looking at Rest PHP frameworks like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)? As @DamienPirsy has said, your project sounds more like you're toying with PHP than developing something that real users would want to use! Also, using the built in PHP server to have a 'server agnostic' setup is like saying I want to use raw files to make my application database agnostic. Save yourself future trouble and use real-world tested tools like Apache and move to other interesting projects! :-)